# Parsing HTML Source to extract Anchor and Link tags href value

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am looking for some HTML Parser in PHP which can help me extract `href values` from the html source.

I looked at [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) and its best but it is to be too overkill for my needs and cosume a lot of CPU doing the extra stuff that I dont need.

I also checked

> $dom = new DomDocument();
>   $dom->loadHTML($html);

but it has problems parsing `HTML5` tags.

Is there any better `library/class` or a way to do it?

Comment: Are you extracting href from only anchor and link tags?  Why would HTML5 tags affect you in this case?  Have you looked at DOMXPath?

Comment: @tandu, `loadHTML` actually validates against HTML4.  Attempts to use HTML5 tags like `<section>` cause warnings.  That said, it did seem to make the tag findable and serializable when I tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use regular expressions to extract the data:

```
$html = "This is some stuff right here. <a href='index.html'>Check this out!</a> <a href=herp.html>And this is another thing!</a> <a href=\"derp.html\">OH MY GOSH</a>";
preg_match_all('/href=[\'"]?([^\s\>\'"]*)[\'"\>]/', $html, $matches);
$hrefs = ($matches[1] ? $matches[1] : false);
print_r($hrefs);
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I further made it case-insensitive and added extra `(a|link)+ ` for parsing only them and exception for spaces, it not seems to be full blown solution `/\s*(a|link)+\s*href=[\'"]?([^\s\>\'"]*)[\'"\>]/i`

Comment: Just a word of warning: that won't validate for `<a class="whatever" href="mypage.htm">...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

simplehtmldom is a handy PHP HTML parsing class

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I used this  - -

```
$html = '<a href="http://google.com"><img src="images/a.png" /></a>';
preg_match('/href="([^\s"]+)/', $html, $match);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($match);
```